# d3.js/LaTeX translation

Tags: d3.js, latex

I'm producing a scientific data visualisation in d3.js, and hence being from the scientific community I am a "LaTeX-er" but very new to d3.js...

I want to include the following in my visualisation (if anyone is familiar with LaTeX):

[image]

Which equates to:

$\text{SFR}$=10.10$\text{M}_{\odot}$ ${\text{ yr}}^{-1}$

How would I go about translating it for rendering for a d3.js viz?

Comment: You could use MathJax to display your formula, see https://gist.github.com/chrisbrich/3391642. Can't help you though as I haven't done this myself before ;)

Comment: I've used MathJax and D3 on the same page [here](http://4c.ucc.ie/~larsko/cs6405/demo/gradient-descent.html).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Nice visualization of Gradient descent.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Nice viz my friend! Really nice. Just a little bug notification: after deleting all the data points we aren't able to add new data...

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Feel free to open an issue on the github page :)

Answer (score 3):

Your LaTeX have couple errors. Corrected version:

```
\text{SFR}_{[\textup{O\ II}]}=10.10\text{M}_{\odot}\ {\text{ yr}}^{-1}
```

Then, you can use `svg:foreignObject` constructor:

```
//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr({"width": 400, "height": 400});

//foreignObject
var latex_raw = "\\text{SFR}_{[\\textup{O\\ II}]}=10.10\\text{M}_{\\odot}\\ {\\text{ yr}}^{-1}";
var latex_render_url = "http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?";
var latex_query = encodeURI(latex_raw);
var latex = svgContainer.append("foreignObject")
     .attr({
         "x": 100,
         "y": 60,
         "width": 400,
         "height": 200,
         "requiredFeatures": "http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"})
     .append("xhtml:body").attr({
         "margin": 0,
         "padding": 0,
         "width": 400,
         "height": 200})
     .append("img").attr({
         "src": latex_render_url + latex_query});
```

NOTICE:

In javascript strings you have to double all the `\` of your LaTeX code!

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4ksjek94/1/